# IIFE: Why does my code ignore an addEventListener if I return an alert without wrapping it in a function?

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

I'm perplexed as to why I have to wrap my alert in a function in order to avoid my code ignoring the event listener.

If I run this code, It'll work properly and I'll be able to click and have the alert display after the click

```
    elem.addEventListener('click', (function(numCopy) {
    return function() {
        alert(numCopy);
    };
})(num));
```

But if I run this code, it'll ignore the event listener and display the alert as soon as the page loads

```
elem.addEventListener('click', (function(numCopy) {
return alert(numCopy);
})(num));
```

I could ignore it and just accept this is the way it's done but I would really appreciate it if someone could explain the logic behind this so I can fully grasp the concept, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Well, it's a function, so `)(num)` after it will call the function immediately. You have to return a function that calls `alert`, not an `alert` call itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets figure out what's going on by looking at the following example:

```
function foo(x) {
  return x;
}

var bar = foo(42);
baz(bar);
```

What is the value passed to `baz`? `42` because `foo` simply returns the value passed to it.

Now lets inline the function *call*:

```
function foo(x) {
  return x;
}

baz(foo(42));
```

What is the value passed to `baz` here? Still `42` whether we assign the return value to a variable or directly pass it to the other function doesn't make a difference.

Now lets inline the function *definition*:

```
baz(function foo(x) { return x; }(42));
```

Now we have an **IIFE**. What is the value passed to `baz` here? Still `42`. We didn't actually change what the code is doing, we just got rid of intermediate variable assignments (we could also drop `foo` from the function expression).

---

How does this related to your code? Lets work our way backwards from your code. We start with:

```
elem.addEventListener('click', (function(numCopy) {
   return alert(numCopy);
})(num));
```

Lets extract the function definition:

```
function foo(numCopy) {
  return alert(numCopy);
}

elem.addEventListener('click', foo(num));
```

Now lets extract the function call:

```
function foo(numCopy) {
  return alert(numCopy);
}

var bar = foo(num);
elem.addEventListener('click', bar);
```

Do you see what's wrong here? You are calling the function (`foo` in this case). The function executes `alert` and that's why you immediately see the alert.

`foo` returns the return value of `alert` (assigned to `bar)`, so you are passing that value to `addEventListener`.

But `alert` returns `undefined` whereas `addEventListener` expects to be passed a function.

That's why your IIFE needs to return a function.